# Hidden links in workbook I can't remove

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have a pretty simple file now that was built on a basis of an old complex file with a lot of links. In this testing file, *Alpha* ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MoMloRxoapCpIb0-zAsFRFHA0mkLwFMk/view?usp=sharing)) there is only 1 value, which refers via formula to 1 value of another workbook. The second workbook (*Beta*) ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QP4hXE2Dsx9nEL9VBHtXCddrflV2USrF/view)) is completely new, except I added there one value.

Issue: when I'm opening workbook *Alpha*, I have a lot of popups that appear after the button in "**Update links**" window was clicked, or when I trigger "**Enable Content**". Popups like this ([screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeQ2B.jpg), [screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQzDd.jpg)) with links to other strange old workbooks and with old paths. I can't understand where should I start searching for reasons of this if I already broke all links in the workbook *Alpha*, which were there, cleaned up all macro were contained, and have only one link to a fresh workbook *Beta* (which have no connection with links you can see in popups).

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Maybe look in Formulas > Name Manager (a guess).

Comment: BigBen, not in this case, all Names are mine in that file, and even when I removed them there is still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after all those weeks I've found out the answer: the reason was in *hidden* names, which you can't see through the usual Name Manager. I've found them and removed via Document Inspector (images):

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjHiE.png)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq1nU.png)

[Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSmHX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some links are hard to find. They can be in formulas, conditional formatting, named ranges, etc.

If you want to speed up the search, you may want to use a 3rd party tool. Long-time Excel MVP Bill Manville wrote a VBA add-in that finds links in the worbook. It's available for free here: https://www.manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm

It has saved me hours of time in many situations.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a great tool. But on my file I have infinite "Looking for links in sheet" status, even If was working on another file I tested.